# finding where the error is with Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a spring boot app in embedded tomcat behind ngix that takes requests and returns a JSON response.  I have a particular method that works great as long as the date range is less than 14 days, regardless of the data amount.  For example, if I submit a request from 1/1/2016 - 1/15/2016 I get results.  But if I request 1/1/16 - 1/16/2016 then an error is returned.  There is no extra data in that extra day, so it can't be payload.

Here is my endpoint:

```
@Controller
@Transactional
public class AppointmentController {

    @RequestMapping(value = APPOINTMENTS_RANGE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<AppointmentDay> getWeekAppointments(@PathVariable String officeName,
                                                                  @PathVariable("startDate")
                                                                  @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate startDate,
                                                                  @PathVariable("endDate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate endDate) {

     Office office = lookupOfficeByUrl(officeName);
     try {
        return appointmentService.buildDateRangeList(office, startDate, endDate);
     } catch (Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
         return new ArrayList();
     }
}
```

}

I have the following debug levels set:

```
logging.level.org.springframework:INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.web: INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.security:TRACE
logging.level.org.springframework.security.web.authentication:TRACE
```

But there is no error thrown, or message in the log files.  This makes me think that the application handles it fine but something else is blowing up.  I have ngix in front of all my web services, and I am new to that so perhaps that is interfering.

Locally, this all works great in IntelliJ or running the jar (java -jar /build/libs/myjar.jar).  There are no exception or errors in the logs or console.  When I step thru, I see that the proper number of objects are returned for a request less than two weeks in range.

Any ideas on what might be affecting these results?  Or the best way to track this down since I don't see anything in the application or console logs?

Comment: It is not really clear what you issue is. Do you see any stack traces or exceptions? If not can you assure that your `appointmentService.buildDateRangeList()` call is returning data for 1/16/2016? I'd suggest that you set a breakpoint and do a step by step analysis.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.   I updated the question but there  are no errors or exceptions thrown.  I step thru the code and see the results being put into the list and returned.  But the JSON response just says "error".  Again, this only happens on a deployed environment not locally via "java -jar" or via IntelliJ.

Comment: If it only occurs in the deployed app try to remote debug it or if that is not feasible go the ugly way and add log statements.

Comment: thank you for the help, it turns out it was an NPE that wasn't being shown for some reason (I am guessing log levels were too high).  Tons of debug statements pointed it out and then it was obvious.  Such a noob mistake!